# Is it possible to generate objects from type-annotated classes for testing?

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-hypothesis, pydantic

I had a look at hypothesis recently and used it like this:

```py
import hypothesis.strategies as s
from hypothesis import given

@given(s.integers(min_value=-(10 ** 6), max_value=10 ** 6))
def test_factorize(an_integer):
    if an_integer == 0:
        # This is tested in `test_factorize_zero` and should throw an exception
        return
    factors = mpu.math.factorize(an_integer)
    product = 1
    for factor in factors:
        product *= factor
    assert product == an_integer
```

This is pretty cool. The main limitation I see is the strategy (e.g. `s.integers`), although [there are a lot of strategies](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html) and I'm still learning which ones there are / how to use them properly.

Is there a strategy to generate objects, given a type-annotated class which uses pydantic?

### My Try

```py
from typing import Optional

from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.strategies import from_type
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Adress(BaseModel):
    city: str
    street: str
    house_number: int
    postal_code: int


class Person(BaseModel):
    prename: str
    middlename: Optional[str]
    lastname: str
    address: Adress


@given(from_type(Person))
def test_me(person: Person):
    assert isinstance(person, Person)
```

when I save this as `test_foo.py` and execute `pytest`, I get:

```
――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― test_me ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

    @given(from_type(Person))
>   def test_me(person: Person):

test_foo.py:20: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

>   ???
E   pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 3 validation errors for Person
E   prename
E     field required (type=value_error.missing)
E   lastname
E     field required (type=value_error.missing)
E   address
E     field required (type=value_error.missing)

pydantic/main.py:283: ValidationError
---------------------------------------------------------------- Hypothesis ----------------------------------------------------------------
You can add @seed(42732672939050403878146949573829059697) to this test or run pytest with --hypothesis-seed=42732672939050403878146949573829059697 to reproduce this failure.
```

I would especially love if hypothesis generated a person without a middle name and a person with a middle name.

Comment: Cool question. I did a little research, and as far as I can tell there's no out of the box solution for that. What one might do is (1) get the schema of the pedantic classes (2) use the named tuple strategy to build tuples that match this schema; (3) initialize pedantic class instances using the named tuple. Could be a nice open source project.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work out of the box, because Hypothesis needs to know what types to use in order to construct a pydantic model, and we've no particular support for pydantic (I've literally only just heard of it from this post).

Roughly there are two things that could be done in order to support it:

1. pydantic could generate correctly typed `__init__` methods. The signature of a pydantic `__init__` method is `__pydantic_self__, **data:Any`, so there's no way for us to know what arguments it expects. If instead the type signature matched that of the field arguments, Hypothesis would work out of the box for this.
2. Someone could write a PR to add pydantic support to hypothesis's `from_type` implementation so that it knows how to construct pydantic models. We've already got custom support for attrs and dataclasses, this would mostly just look like that.

My preferred solution would be the first if pydantic developers are open to it.

In the meantime, you [can use the `builds` function to define custom strategies for your models](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.builds). You can then [register it as the strategy for that type](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html?highlight=register_type_strategy#hypothesis.strategies.register_type_strategy) or just use it directly.

Comment: TL;DR: In principle it is possible and the code above would be correct, but it is not possible at the moment. Either `pydantic` or `hypothesis` would require additional work. I've let the developers of pydantic know of this: [issue 1666](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1666)

Comment: Thank your for your help 

Comment: Update: It works with `hypothesis==5.18.3` and `pydantic==1.5.1`. Could you maybe add that to your answer?